# How to position buttons next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have just stared with web design and I am trying to implement something simple but im not sure what the best method would be to achieve this.

What I'm simply trying to do is position buttons next to one another regardless of the length of the text before it. IE as seen by the screenshot below I have 4 columns with paragraphs and buttons.

[image]

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS in the question, rather than sharing a screenshot. Otherwise your question risks being closed. See the Help Center on Asking Questions for more information.

Comment: it would make helping you a lot easier if you added your code

Comment: Please be more specific: would you like to make all Buttons of the same fixed width, or resizable? Also, @TylerH is right: plz include your code sample and highlight the problematic part. Best regards,

Comment: Another possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308951/aligning-elements-at-the-bottom-of-multiple-columns

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481612/align-variable-height-child-div-to-bottom-of-variable-height-parent-div-while-a

Comment: My sincere apologies regarding the duplicate question. Thank you all for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

```
div {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
}
ul {
    display: -webkit-flex;
}

li {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/pTsW4/85/**

[browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pTsW4/87/

```
* { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none; 
    box-sizing: border-box;  
 }


ul {
    margin: 0;
    display:table;
}

li {
    display:table-cell;
    width:30%;
    padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Adding display table to the 'ul' and table-cell to the child 'li's is to ensure equal height. A padding bottom of 40px is added to give room for the buttons and then the buttons are absolutely positioned to the bottom of the 'li's.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how broad flexbox is supported. I'd go for the separate div or a solution in which jQuery applies [equal height](http://www.broken-links.com/2009/01/20/very-quick-equal-height-columns-in-jquery/) on all (relative) columns, and then position the buttons on the bottom (absolute).

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;` on parent container to assure all blocks have same height. Then position `<button>` absolute from `bottom` and `left`. Center by x-translating -50% of button's width to the left.

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPyLGK

```css
ul {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 600px;
}

li{
  background-color: #eeeef0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666;
  flex-grow: 3;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

li p {
  text-align: left;
}

li button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Test 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/150" />
    <button>Go now!</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Test 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/160" />
    <button>Go now!</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Test 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/260" />
    <button>Go now!</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Test 4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Go now!</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This could use a note that IE10 and older won't work with `display: flex;`

Comment: IE10 does have support for flex box, but in fact it uses the 2012 version of the syntax. In case anyone's interested, it's here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/

Comment: That's right; it's also behind an `-ms-` prefix.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the buttons in a separate div:

```
<div><p>Text 1</p></div>
<div><p>Text 2</p></div>
<div><p>Text 3</p></div>
<div><p>Text 4</p></div>
<div>...buttons...</div>
```

Then position the div with css.

Answer (score -1):

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6zv6xtay/1/)

```
    <tr>
        <td> Funny Hello Images</td>
        <td> Funny Hello Images</td>
        <td> Funny Hello Images</td>
        <td> Funny Hello Images</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Find the best Hello images, greetings and pictures here. Browse our great collection of hello pictures and choose your favourite to send to a friend.</td>
        <td> Share an image on Facebook by clicking the button below the graphic, or copying and pasting the link.</td>
        <td>Share an image on Facebook by clicking the button below the graphic, or copying and pasting the link.</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <button>button1</button></td>
        <td> <button>button2</button></td>
        <td> <button>button3</button></td>
        <td> <button>button4</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table td { 
    table-layout:fixed;
  width:20%;
  overflow:hidden;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Updated the Link